# Does including a scaler in sklearn's Pipeline scale the target variable?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, pipeline

When using a scaling function in  `sklearn`'s Pipeline utility, is the scalar applied to the target variable during training and prediction?

In other words, is my code below, which makes use of `TransformedTargetRegressor` redundant to the pipeline?

```
cowboy = Lasso(max_iter=10000, tol=.005)
climber = Ridge()
gymshorts = ElasticNet()
scaler = pre.RobustScaler()

models = [('xgb', xgb.XGBRegressor(**best_params)),
          ('ridge', make_pipeline(scaler, TransformedTargetRegressor(climber, scaler))),
          ('lasso', make_pipeline(scaler, TransformedTargetRegressor(cowboy, scaler))),
          ('enet', make_pipeline(scaler, TransformedTargetRegressor(gymshorts, scaler)))]

stack = ensemble.StackingRegressor(estimators=models)
stack = stack.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In sklearn's Pipeline, the scaler isn't applied to the target. Only independent varibales (aka features) get scaled.

Thus, the use of `TransformedTargetRegressor` in your code is not redundant.